# is there a way to read iphone messages through python?

Tags: python, sms

I am working on a project that requires the program to take in text received via SMS. But, whenever I look on the internet, I find services like twilio, which works only through an external number. That is, one may send a text to the twilio number so that the python program may receive and process it.

For my purposes, I intend people texting me through my personal number, and python accessing the body of that text for processing. Is there any way to do this? (PS: i don't have a mac)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [this](http://www.allyourtexts.com/). It’s not in python, but there having a solution in python isn’t that simple, hence not that popular